# GHC Targeting Multiple Platforms

Tags: haskell, ghc, cross-compiling

Maybe I'm missing something, but the GHC docs on cross compilation are not very explicit.

http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/CrossCompiling

Any good examples out there on cross compiling with GHC?  I'm currently attempting to build on Mac OSX and target Windows.

Comment: Have you tried to compile [mingw for OSX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)?

Comment: I'm not following...I am trying to compile Haskell code on Mac OSX to a Windows binary.  I am trying to avoid doing all of this in a Windows VM.

Comment: mingw are cross-compilers gcc's designed to work in a Unix environment for windows targets. (Also, please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually.)